# How do vetoes affect re-votes in US Congress?

Tags: united-states, congress, veto

I would think that a president challenging the will of congress would cause congress to vote differently out of principle but am curious if this is true.

Throughout history, what is the percentage increase or decrease in congressmen and women who vote for a bill after it has been vetoed?

cross-asked on history.stackexchange [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51575/how-do-vetoes-effect-re-votes-in-us-congress)

Comment: It seems like pretty much all of the information needed to answer this can be found on [this US Senate page](https://www.senate.gov/reference/Legislation/Vetoes/vetoCounts.htm). It has the number of successful/overriden/pocket vetoes per president, and each veto seems to have links to both the original bill and the vote on whether or not it was overriden (the more modern presidents have more standardized info). It's a lot of data to crawl through to get a meaningful answer though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-votes are going to be biased toward those that would override the veto.  It's likely that a Speaker or a Majority leader would simply refuse to hold a vote to override when the votes aren't there.  Why bother holding a show vote if nothing's going to happen?  The Congress already did their part politically by going on record for the bill and putting it in front of the President, why embarrass themselves with a defeat?  (of course, it's possible that the Majority leader in this case may *want* to embarrass the Senators who voted for it).

Comment: The very, very good point here is that a vote to pass a bill pre-veto and a vote to override a veto are two completely different kinds of votes. As in so different that I'm not sure there's any information that can be gained by comparing them.

Comment: Which is what I was wondering as well. If the House takes up and passes a veto override, can the Senate Majority leader refuse to take up the bill?

Comment: @BobE - That'd be a good question to ask.  I'd like to know the answer, too.

Comment: @BobE  If he can, then it won't matter :-P  A bill in the Senate requires 67 votes.  Any Senator can call up a bill that is in order, and 60 votes can end any debate. Which means that if they have 67 votes, they have more than enough Senators that they can force a vote. And if they don't have enough to force a vote, they can't possibly override the veto.

Comment: @Bobson -Procedure is outline here [ https://www.senate.gov/CRSpubs/2b1325dc-6a6b-42c4-9a08-506c3a59a251.pdf  , the salient point about proceding to a vote on the reconsideration of a vetoed bill is outlined on page 3 and 4. The ' money line' is: "once a veto message has been laid before the Senate, It could also be tabled or indefinitely postponed, which would preclude any further action on the matter"

Comment: @DavidRice - I could picture a scenario where there might be 7+ Senators who feel like politically and/or morally they'd have to vote in favor of the bill if it came up again, but would rather avoid that uncomfortable situation by voting against ending debate.